# String Comparison Issue in Java

Tags: java, string

techpalle;

```
public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Tri" + "angle" =="Triangle"); 

    }

}
```

Tri is stored in string constant pool, angle is also stored in string constant pool and after concatenation is done Triangle will be stored in heap memory.

Right Hand Side Triangle will be stored in string constant pool
`==` compares the address
How am I getting true then?

Comment: First "Tri" + "angle" is determined to be "Triangle". After that the comparison using == is made, yielding true.

Comment: Concatenation of string literals is done at compile time - the compiler is smart enough to create one string `"Triangle"` out of `"Tri" + "angle"`.

Comment: == compares address right?